# Passing MFC Objects arugements between functions by reference (CObList)

Tags: c++, pointers, mfc

Very simple C++ question but I've done some googling and can only seem to find the answer for the newer std:: methods, and unless I'm doing something wrong this doesn't appear to be working.

Question: How do I copy, by reference, a CObList as a function argument.
Current Error: "Cannot convert parameter 3 from 'class CObList' to 'class CObList'

Background:
I'm modifying some old legacy code, so I unfortunately have to use a CObList of custom objects named cInventoryDetail instantiated form another class as that's being populated upstream and my data is in that.

I'm getting the error listed above when attempting to pass it by value or reference using the & prefix in the declaration & definition. Is there a way to pass this entire list by reference so I can access the data?

Additional Question:
I tried prefixing it with & in the definition and declaration but with no luck. 
The class doing this processing is a class instantiated by the main class that contains the COBList, so I also tried using "this" with no luck as it appears to just reference the class I'm currently in without being able to reference the current instantiated base class.

In additon to the COBList question, is there a way to use this to reference the calling class and not the current class?

Comment: Put the source code and the exact error you're getting

Comment: Is your `CInventoryDetail` class derived from `CObject`? If no there is no need to use `CObList`. This container has been designed to hold things like `CWnd` which is not copyable.  You should use `CList<CInventoryDetail*>` instead.

Comment: You seem to be confused about basic C++ syntax here. There is no `&` **prefix** when using references. The formal parameter is of type `CObList&`. At the call site you pass the object the same way you pass an object by value. C++ does not differentiate between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference at the call site.

Comment: Andrew - CInventoryDetail is not a derived class. One of the attributes / members on the CInventoryDetail  class is a COBList which is being populated in one of the public methods with instances of a different object / class.  There is an instantiation of another object in the CInventoryDetail class as a separate member which has its own private function which needs access to the CInventoryDetail's COBList in order to perform some relevant queries to populate that class'es data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspectable - My syntax was wrong. Making it a suffix appears to have corrected it. Thank you.

Declaration, Call & Definition

```
DoSomething(CObList&);
DoSomething(m_myList);
DoSomething(CObList& m_myLIst);
```

Comment: What? You should never use a `m_` beginning variable as a name for a function parameter! Variables beginning with `m_`should be only the ones that are members of a class! That is the meaning of it using *Hungarian notation*! I did a refactoring of a whole project some time ago just to remove exactly this! It was becoming extremely confuse to know whether a variable was a parameter or a member!

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Unfortunately this is was an inherited app that suffered the same issue you have mentioned (being notated incorrectly). This has now been fixed.